# Unfortunately Delete Xcode Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Unfortunately, Delete Xcode Simulator from

Home Directory >> Application >> Xcode (Right-click >> Show Pakcage Contants) >> Content >> Developer >> Applications >> simulator

Then clean the Empty Bin

How can I again get back my simulator

Answer (score 1):

In XCode menu select

Window -> Devices & Simulators

select Simulator tab in the popup window there is + icon in the bottom corner. 
you can selet and add simulator by clicking the "+" button.

Comment: Not Working Although it added a new one after clicking the bottom left "+" button but it's color still white and the project can not build by it still >>>> waiting for the correct answer

Comment: I try it but nor working I am not sure but I think someone gives me the file by email or anywhere then if I put it this directory then it should fixed do you give me in my email at ashfaqur.rahman80@gmail.com

Comment: also check show as run destination check box in devices and simulators. i think there is no other way to add simulator to xcode

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I did it before but not working. Please show me the right path

Comment: can you plese test by creating a new project and running it on simulator. also try restrating the system??

Comment: ok give me some moment I try it then gets back to you for my feedback

Comment: After restart and creating a new project then when I click build and run button then show >>>>>>> Unable to find Simulator.app. If you have another Idea or give me the file in my email the file doesn't lyes in online. you can find that file in Home Directory >> Application >> Xcode (Right-click >> Show Package Contents) >> Content >> Developer >> Applications >> simulator